# How to compare linked lists?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

At first want to tell how this programm works. We need to compare two linked lists and find out if one of them contains in another. My idea is if one is bigger then compare the smaller one with him. So we just replace our Linked Lists and use the same function. "number_elem" answer us how many matches must be. But there is a problem when Linked List have two or more same elements<  as i thought need to replace it with another number when it have a match. But i need to use a list further and as we can see in last printf's we have troubles with that. Write your ideas please, or a code,because the only way i see is create another list and copy.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
struct uzel {
    int n;
    struct uzel *next;};

struct uzel* initialize(struct uzel *head){
    int a;
    printf("uzel = " );
    scanf("%d", &a);
    if (a == 0){
        head->next = NULL;
        } else {
            head->n = a;
            head->next = malloc(sizeof(struct uzel));
            initialize(head->next);
        }
    return head;
}

void gprint(struct uzel *head){
    printf("(");
    while (head->next != NULL){
        printf("%d ", head->n);
        head = head->next;}
    printf(")\n");}
int compare(struct uzel *head_1, struct uzel *head_2,int i)
{
    int t=0;
    struct uzel *compare_1=head_1;
    struct uzel *compare_2=head_2;
   while ((compare_1->next!=NULL)&&(compare_2->next!=NULL))
 {
  if((compare_1->n)==(compare_2->n))
    {
        compare_1=head_1;
        compare_2->n=2147483647;//Here!
        compare_2=compare_2->next;
        t++;
    }
    else
    {
        compare_1=compare_1->next;
    }
}
    if(t==i)
        return 1;
        else
            return 0;
}

int number_elem(struct uzel* head)
{
    int i=0;
    struct uzel* kolvo=head;
    while(kolvo)
    {
       i++;
        kolvo=kolvo->next;
    }
   return i;
}

int main()
{
    struct uzel head1;
    int i,g;
    initialize(&head1);
    struct uzel mainhead=head1;
    i=number_elem(&mainhead);
    i--;
    printf("%d\n",i);
    gprint(&head1);
    struct uzel head2;
    struct uzel*mainhead1=initialize(&head2);
    g=number_elem(mainhead1);
    g--;
    printf("%d\n",g);
    gprint(&head2);
    printf("Lets check ur linked lists\n");
    int a=0;
    if(i<=g)
    {
        a=compare(mainhead1,&mainhead,i);
    }
    else{
        a=compare(&mainhead,mainhead1,g);
    }
    if(a){
        printf("YES\n");}
    else{
        printf("NOPE\n");}
    gprint(&head1);
    gprint(&head2);
}
```

Comment: Please use the title to communicate the *technical problem* at hand.

Comment: What is the range of valid 'uzel'?

Comment: suggest:  1) clarify your criteria regarding what you consider a 'match'  2) sort each list  'qsort()` 3) consider what to do with duplicate values in  any one list `uniq()`